# Multiple arguments for last parameter

Tags: php, functions, argparse

I have function that has three parameters, called `key`, `value` and `attribute`.

Parameter `attribute` may be empty or have within two arguments. Code of function below is shortened (deprived of arguments validation)

```
public function Set_ContentUsage($Key, $Value, $Attribute=NULL)
{
    $this -> ContentUsage = array();
    $Attribute = array_slice(func_get_args(), 2);

    /* validation of arguments */

    $this -> ContentUsage['key'] = $Key;
    $this -> ContentUsage['value'] = $Value;


    if(count($Attribute) == 1)
    {
        $this -> ContentUsage['keyattr'] = ($Key == MarC::MARC_OPTION_ATTRVAL) ? $Attribute[0] : FALSE;
        $this -> ContentUsage['valueattr'] = ($Value == MarC::MARC_OPTION_ATTRVAL) ? $Attribute[0] : FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        $this -> ContentUsage['keyattr'] = $Attribute[0];
        $this -> ContentUsage['valueattr'] = $Attribute[1];
    }
}
```

My question is **how to improve this function to get multiple arguments for  parameter `$Attribute` without `$Attribute = array_slice(func_get_args(), 2);`?**

I found that if I only delete

`$Attribute = array_slice(func_get_args(), 2);`

it leads to malfunction of rest code.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit unclear, but I'll assume you're referring to the use of `array_slice(func_get_args(), 2);` to implement what I'm used to calling a "rest parameter", which results in a very misleading function signature.

The simplest and cleanest alternative is to use the ... operator [added in PHP 5.6](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php).

```
public function Set_ContentUsage($Key, $Value, ...$Attribute) {
    $firstAttribute = $Attribute[0];
    ...
}
```

This makes it immediately obvious to anyone reading your code that the last parameter is meant to be an array of all remaining arguments.

If this is not an option, then you'll simply have to change this function's call sites to pass an actual array for the third argument, or stick to `func_get_args()` until you can upgrade to 5.6.

Comment: Explanation on PHP.net is written very uncleary, but I suppose that with PHP 5.6 instead `func_get_args()` I need only to use something like `$NameOfParam[$Index]` to get nth argument. Please, (if I am right in this), write this into your answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @Václav Added that to the sample code snippet